# What will happen if you filed your taxes with two different locations? How can it be solved?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, canada, child-care

I was living in Winnipeg, Manitoba and I had done my taxes online with H&R Canada Online. H&R Canada provided me with some papers to print out and then it was settled, I moved to Sudbury, Ontario. Nothing had happened with the file that I sent in with H&R Canada so I filed once again with the same taxing company, but a different address. Does anyone know what will happen? How to resolve this? If you can, let me know as soon as possible. I have to get all my taxes sorted out before my son arrives into the world.